# asynchronous ajax request not working asynchronously

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following problem: I'm using jQuery ajax requests to add or delete entries from a server file.

My code works insofar as the entries are added and deleted as expected when clicking on the respective buttons.

However, the action adding entries is not done asynchronously. That is, I have to reload the whole page before the respective action takes effect.

I have not(!!) changed the default settings of the ajax request, i.e. I have not added "Async: false". Still, the code isn't working asynchronously. (I even tried  adding "Async: true" to explicitly say that the request is to be made asynchronously ... however, to no avail) .

Here is the ajax method that isn't working as expected:

```
        $("button").on("click", function(){

            var name = $("#name").val();
            var text = $("#text").val();

            $.post(url, {name: name, text: text});

        });
```

Why is this request not asynchronous? How can I make it asynchronous?

***************************UPDATE*********************************************

The following screenshot provides some details regarding the server/language:

[image]

****************************UPDATE2***********************************************

Here is - for context - the code in its entirety:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de-DE">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <style>
            body {
                font: 15px normal Arial, sans-serif;
                color: #000000;
            }
            label {
                width: 5em;
                display: inline-block;
            }
            ul {
                padding: 0;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var url = "https://vsr.informatik.tu-chemnitz.de/edu/2015/evs/exercises/jsajax/guestbook.php";

            $.get(url, function(data){

                var table = document.createElement("table");
                $("body").append(table);
                var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
                $("table").append(tbody);

                for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                    $("tbody").append("<tr><td>" + data[i]["name"] + "</td><td>" + data[i]["text"] + "</td><td><a id=\"" + data[i]["id"] + "\" href=\"#\">Delete</a></td></tr>");       
                }

            });


            $("body").on("click", "a", function(e){

                e.preventDefault();
                var ID = $(this).attr("id");

                $.ajax({
                    url: url + '?' + $.param({"id": ID}),
                    type: 'DELETE',
                    success: function(){$("#" + ID).closest("tr").remove();},
                    error: function(){alert("error");}          
                });

            });


            $("button").on("click", function(){

                var name = $("#name").val();
                var text = $("#text").val();

                $.post(url, {name: name, text: text});

            });


        });          
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Guestbook</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><b>TestUser:</b> This is an example entry. <a href="#" alt="Delete entry">(X)</a></li>
            <li><b>TestUser2:</b> This is another example entry. <a href="#" alt="Delete entry">(X)</a></li>
        </ul>
        <hr>
        <form method="POST" action="https://vsr.informatik.tu-chemnitz.de/edu/2015/evs/exercises/jsajax/guestbook.php">
                <label for="name">Name</label> <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"><br>
                <label for="text">Text</label> <input id="text" type="text" name="text" placeholder="Text"><br>
                <button type="submit">Add entry</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

*********************************UPDATE4*****************************************

After adding something, I'm redirected to a page with containing a message looking similar to the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I'll give you a hint: `this` in your success callback isn't the same `this` that you're getting an id from....

Comment: @JaredSmith is that a hint, mate? That is the answer to this problem

Comment: @JaredSmith Thank you very much ... the delete request now works asynchronously ... However, the post request is still synchronous ... Do you also know why this might be?

Comment: The request is async. If it weren't *you wouldn't be able to interact with the page* (which is why synchronous requests are bad). So I'm not sure what you mean by "synchronous".

Comment: @JaredSmith The post request isn't working asynchronously ... When pressing the button, I am referred to another page with the following content:

Comment: {"message": "Error occurred"}

Comment: I then have to press the "back"-button to get back to the original page ... there the entry has been deleted (as requested) ...

Comment: Stop trying to tell us what *you* think your problem is and post all the relevant code. Your request is async. Period. Async is the default, and it has been for years. Sync has been deprecated and won't even work anymore in chrome IIRC. The fact you're getting redirected is due to something else, likely code you didn't post. Redirects don't just happen.

Comment: ok, I will post the code

Comment: Added answer. In the future, as is recommended in the help center under how to ask questions, I'd advise you to not try to diagnose problems yourself but just the code, what its doing, and what you want it to do.

Comment: ok, thanks ... will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're doing a form submit that takes you to a different page. If you want to stay on the same page then get rid of the form submit and use the jquery post request as you've written it, possibly with a success callback. But don't try to mix the two. If you want to async and then redirect, just do the redirect in JavaScript from the success handler of your jquery post request.

Comment: Another option would be to catch the form submit event, cancel the form submission and then do your Ajax in that handler.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the comments, this is what they are suggesting:

```
  $("body").on("click", "a", function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var $that = $(this);
        var ID = $that.attr("id");

        $.ajax({
            url: url + '?' + $.param({"id": ID}),
            type: 'DELETE',
            success: function(){$that.closest("tr").remove();},
            error: function(){alert("error");}          
        });

    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I got that. But why is the other request not asynchronous